Face Detection is not proper while integrating OpenCV with native iOS
I am trying to integrate openCV with native iOS app, The problem I am facing is my code is not able to detect faces properly and draw a bounding box around the same. Here is the complete source code, please drag and drop the openCV iOS framework in the project if you decide to clone as it was too large for GitHub so I had to remove it.
So here is my Objective-C++ code
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"

@interface UIImage (OpenCVWrapper)
- (void)convertToMat: (cv::Mat *)pMat: (bool)alphaExists;
@end

@implementation UIImage (OpenCVWrapper)

- (void)convertToMat: (cv::Mat *)pMat: (bool)alphaExists {
    UIImageOrientation orientation = self.imageOrientation;
    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(self, mat, alphaExists);
    
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            cv::rotate(mat, *pMat, cv::ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            cv::rotate(mat, *pMat, cv::ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            cv::rotate(mat, *pMat, cv::ROTATE_180);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        default:
            *pMat = mat;
            break;
    }
}
@end

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

static cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade;

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [OpenCVWrapper self]) {
        NSString *faceCascadePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_default" ofType:@"xml"];
        if (!faceCascade.load([faceCascadePath UTF8String])) {
            NSLog(@"Error loading face detection model");
        }
    }
}

+ (NSArray<NSValue *> *)detectFaceRectsInUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // Convert UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat mat;
    [image convertToMat:&mat :false];

    // Convert the image to grayscale
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::equalizeHist(gray, gray);

    // Detect faces
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | cv::CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));

    // Convert cv::Rect to CGRect and wrap in NSValue
    NSMutableArray<NSValue *> *faceRects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:faces.size()];
    for (const auto &face : faces) {
        CGRect faceRect = CGRectMake(face.x, face.y, face.width, face.height);
        [faceRects addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:faceRect]];
    }

    return [faceRects copy];
}

@end

Following is my swift code
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import VideoToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    var previewView : UIView!
    var boxView:UIView!
    
    //Camera Capture requiered properties
    var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
    var videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue!
    var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private var faceOverlayView: FaceOverlayView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            previewView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                               y: 0,
                                               width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                               height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
            previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
            view.addSubview(previewView)
            
            boxView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
            view.addSubview(boxView)
            
            // Initialize face overlay view
            faceOverlayView = FaceOverlayView(frame: view.bounds)
            view.addSubview(faceOverlayView)
            
            
            setupAVCapture()
    }
    
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft ||
            UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight ||
            UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.unknown) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    func setupAVCapture(){
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice
            .default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                     for: .video,
                     position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) else {
            return
        }
        captureDevice = device
        beginSession()
    }
    
    func beginSession(){
        var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            guard deviceInput != nil else {
                print("error: cant get deviceInput")
                return
            }
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
                self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
            }
            
            videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
            videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)
            
            if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
                session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
            }
            
            videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.isEnabled = true
            
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            
            let rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer
            rootLayer.masksToBounds=true
            previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
            rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                self.session.startRunning()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            deviceInput = nil
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return  }
        
        guard let image = UIImage(pixelBuffer: imageBuffer) else {
            return
        }
        detectFaces(in: image)
        //stopCamera()
    }
    
    
    
    func stopCamera(){
        session.stopRunning()
    }
    
    
    private func detectFaces(in image: UIImage) {
        guard let faceRects = OpenCVWrapper.detectFaceRects(in: image) else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let viewWidth = self.faceOverlayView.bounds.width
            let viewHeight = self.faceOverlayView.bounds.height
            let imageWidth = image.size.width
            let imageHeight = image.size.height
            
            let scaleX = viewWidth / imageWidth
            let scaleY = viewHeight / imageHeight
            
            let scaleFactor = min(scaleX, scaleY)
            
            let offsetX = (viewWidth - imageWidth * scaleFactor) / 2
            let offsetY = (viewHeight - imageHeight * scaleFactor) / 2
            
            let transformedRects = faceRects.map { $0.cgRectValue }.map { face in
                return CGRect(
                    x: face.origin.x * scaleFactor + offsetX,
                    y: face.origin.y * scaleFactor + offsetY,
                    width: face.size.width * scaleFactor,
                    height: face.size.height * scaleFactor
                )
            }
            
            self.faceOverlayView.setFaces(transformedRects)
        }
    }
    
    
}


extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        var cgImage: CGImage?
        VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)
        
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}

I am able to build the project properly, just the face detection part is a bit off and not sure what else needs to be added

If you are complaining about accuracy, I think it is not about the code but the model you are using.  Cascade models are faster but their accuracy is really low. You can improve it by optimizing the parameters.My suggestion is switching to.other models

and you keep reloading the cascade classifier for every video frame... [mre] also requires you to debug your code. "profiling" is part of that.

@YunusTemurlenk can you guide on what other models are there in opencv?

@ChristophRackwitz I made changes to what you suggested

You can try dlib, tensorflow models for better results

@YunusTemurlenk thanks but I think the problem is not with opencv, because the same thing works fine with android
